# Can a third-party developer develop a plug-in for Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, plugins

I see that Adobe Acrobat has some plug-ins:

[image: d-]

Can a third-party developer (= someone who doesn't have access to Adobe Acrobat's internal code/information) develop a plug-in for Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show the minimum necessary effort for a question.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/plugin_apps_developer_guide.pdf and https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html Anything else is a license question, which is a legal question, which is off topic here.

Comment: @music2myear Your document dates back from 2007, so it's unclear whether it is still supported. I have no idea where you see legal questions. I Googled but didn't find anything; I didn't expect it to be part of the SDK.

Comment: "can a..." has two aspects: "is it technically possible" and the answer to that depends on publicly available information, and "does the license allow" which is a legal question.

Comment: SDKs exist to allow third party extension of a product

Comment: @music2myear if you want to stretch things, can also has a physical aspect... "SDKs exist to allow third party extension of a product" -> not necessarily as plug-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. That's usually the main idea behind the plug-in system.

You may want to check out:

- [Acrobat Developer Center](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html)
- [What is the Acrobat Software Developer Kit?](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html)
- [Plug-in architecture](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/plug_in_architecture.html)

Comment: Thanks. "That's the main idea behind the plug-in system in basically any case." -> sometimes it's not exposed to / documented for third-party developers.